# Fetch Data in react after Page Index change

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching data from an api and pass pageIndex = 1 and get 10 first items and pageIndex 2  getting second 10 items and so on , then when user clicks on nextPage/prevPage , PageIndex will increase/decrease and I want to fetch data again , how should I do this in react :

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
const [index, setActiveStep] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
     const getData = async () => {
     const dataFromServer = await fetchData()
  setData(dataFromServer )
} 
getData() }, [])

// Pagination
const forwardButton = () => { 
  setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1); 
}; 

// Pagination
const previousButton = () => { 
  setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) =>  prevActiveStep + 1 ); 
}; 

const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`api?page=${index + 1}`)
    const data = await res.json()
    TOTAL_ITEMS = data.totalItems
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useEffect will trigger when index is modified. You can fetch data when user click on prev or  ext button

```
useEffect(() => {
     const getData = async () => {
        const dataFromServer = await fetchData();
        setData(dataFromServer);
      } 
     getData();
}, [index])
```